# Modify AVCaptureSession before saving with AVCaptureMovieFileOutput

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturemoviefileoutput

**Use Case:** I want to capture input from the camera, draw on top of the captured frames (and sound) and save the result as a .mov file.

- *I see that I can capture input for the camera using AVCaptureSession.*
- *I can save this to a .mov file using AVCaptureMovieFileOutput.*
- *AVVideoComposition can be used to add Core Animation for playback. I assume for recording somehow too?*

**Problem:** I can't see how to modify the input before it is saved to file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [RosyWriter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011110) was almost doing what I wanted. Adding the following code to captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection: enabled me to draw onto the frame using Quartz.

```
    CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);
    NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);

    CGSize frameSize = CGSizeMake(self.videoDimensions.width, self.videoDimensions.height);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, frameSize.width,
                                                 frameSize.height, 8, 4*frameSize.width, rgbColorSpace, 
                                                 kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100, 100);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 200, 200);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

`AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` does not let you process captured frames. To do that, replace it with `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and encode the input to a .mov file using an `AVAssetWriter`.

As for the `AVVideoComposition`, I think you may have to apply it in a separate pass with an `AVAssetExportSession`.