# Modify video frames with captureOutput(_:didOutput:from:)

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I have a video recorder app that uses AVCaptureMovieFileOutput to write a movie recording. Now I want to render something additional into the framebuffer frames that are recorded.

I know I could use AssetWriter to write my own movie file by using the framebuffer data inside capture_Ouput(), but that is not an option here...

Question: Is it possible to modify camera frames with AVCaptureVideoDataOutput/capture_Output before they get stored using AVCaptureMovieFileOutput?

In other words: Is the framebuffer data delivered by capture_Output a copy of the camera frames or are they the session's "original" ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159819/modify-avcapturesession-before-saving-with-avcapturemoviefileoutput ?

Comment: No, because my question was if AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and  AVCaptureMovieFileOutput can be used concurrently on the same session. Did anybody do that ? My test indicate that once AVCaptureMovieFileOutput is added to the session captureOutput is never being called. Can anybody confirm this ?